# How can I display numbers with different arithmetic operator

Tags: android

I'm trying to display different expressions with different arithmetic operator for example **2+6=**, **7-1=**, **9*2=**, **10/5=**. From the code I have at the moment only integers with the `"/"` operator are working, other operators don't. My code is:

```
fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             display.setText(fnum0+"+"+ snum0+"= ");

             fnum1 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             snum1 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             display.setText(fnum1+"-"+ snum1+"= ");

             fnum2 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             snum2= (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             display.setText(fnum2+"*"+ snum2+"= ");

             fnum3= (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             snum3= (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
             display.setText(fnum3+"/"+ snum3+"= ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting the text 4 times effectively overwriting the text for each subsequent call.

If you want all 4 of the expressions in the text you have to concatenate all the strings like this:

```
display.setText(fname0 + "+" + snum0+"=\n"+fname1 + "-" + snum1+"=\n"+fname2 + "*" + snum2+"=\n"+fname3 + "/" + snum3+"=\n");
```

I would also recommend that you make it a little more readable by creating a string and appending it.

```
String str = fname0 + "+" + snum0+"=\n";
str += fname1 + "-" + snum1+"=\n";
str += fname2 + "*" + snum2+"=\n";
str += fname3 + "/" + snum3+"=\n";

display.setText(str);
```

To do a  random operation try this.

```
fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
String str = "";
int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 4)));

if(operation == 0) 
   str = fnum0 + "+" + snum0;
else if(operation == 1)
   str = fnum0 + "-" + snum0;
else if(operation == 2) 
   str = fnum0 + "*" + snum0;
else 
   str = fnum0 + "/" + snum0;

display.setText(str);
```

Basically this generates a random number from 0 to 3 and uses that to determine which operation is displayed

Comment: Will the code that you have writtem give me all for operators in one expression?

Comment: It should with a line break char `"\n"` in between them all if you want to display one of the 4 lines you will have to wrap the code you have in an `if statement` that determines which one you display.

Comment: i want it to display randomely with different operators. IS there anyway i can do that?

Comment: how can do i remove the restriction from the random number like it can be any random number but 2 integers but consist of ten questions

Comment: `Math.random()` generates a number from 0.0 to 1.0 multiplying this by a number (N) generates a random number between 0 and N-1. If you want any random number you can make this `Integer.Max_Value`. If you then want 10 of them what I would do is make the above code a method (except for the `display.setText(str);` and call it ten times to create 10 strings and concat those strings and then set the text to the concatenated string.

Comment: so can i use the above code to display ten question with random operation?

Comment: yeah basically. Create a method that does the above and returns the string of the equation. Then whenever you want a random equation call the function and you'll get one. You can call the function any number of times to get the string.

Answer (score 1):

It displays the '/' operation (last one) only because you overwrite the previous operation string each time you call `setText()`. You need to call that method with your finally formed string. Therefore you can use the `append()` function to concatenate the strings and represent them all in your display view.

Try the following:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(1000);
fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
str.append(fnum0+" + "+ snum0+"= \n");
fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
str.append(fnum0+" - "+ snum0+"= \n");
fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
str.append(fnum0+" * "+ snum0+"= \n");
fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
str.append(fnum0+" / "+ snum0+"= \n");

display.setText(str);
```

Comment: will that code display each expression with a differen operator?

Comment: Yes it will display each expression with four different arithmatic operators (+-/*) in each line. That's what you wanted I suppose, right?

Comment: yes, it was kind of right but i wanted to display each operator everytime a button is pressed